# Stop long header breaking li list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am working on a site that displays items within a list. Now I am finding that if the title (e.g roller blinds) breaks into two lines, it messes up the rest of the layout below. How can I change this so this doesn't happen? I need to retain the option of a longer title.

CSS:

```
#solutions-categories .inner-box{
    padding:20px;}

#solutions-categories ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0px -10px;
    list-style:none;}

#solutions-categories ul li.solution-category{
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    padding:0px 10px 40px 10px;}

.solutions-category-image{
    margin-bottom:20px;}

.solutions-category-image img{
    height:auto;
    width:100%;}

.solutions-category-title h3{
    margin: 25px 0px 15px 0px;}

.solutions-category-title .divider{
    margin-bottom: 25px !important;}
```

Now I tried changing this to floated divs rather than li elements, I've tried using JS to create equal heights but nothing works.

Comment: Can't you create a MCVE?

Comment: And add the picture of desirable result please.

Comment: (Hi Charly. I notice some of your questions have a link `dev.charlyanderson.co.uk` which appears to have expired and gone to parking. Is there a replacement for this site, so links going to the old domain can be repaired instead of deleted?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Allow vertical space to accommodate the longest likely title, or 2) use JavaScript to calculate the tallest and make them all match.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var maxTitleHt = 0;

    $('.solutions-category-title h3').each(function() {
        var titleHt = $(this).height();

        if (titleHt > maxTitleHt) {
            maxTitleHt = titleHt;
        }

        $(this).height(maxTitleHt);
    });
});
```

You probably want to name that and run it on window resize to update them.